# How to delete singleton instance from separate module before system killed running threads

Tags: c++, multithreading

I have a C++ Windows (compiled with Visual Studio 2019) program that uses shared libraries. A shared library uses a singleton on a class that creates a thread. The class destructor kills the thread cleanly, so there should be no memory leak. However, I see that the destructor is being invoked after the system actually killed all running threads upon exit, so it's too late, the thread is not exited cleanly and this introduces a memory leak (and possibly other problems depending on the code being processed by the thread).

Here is a MCVE:

```
#include <thread>
#include <atomic>

class Single
{
public:
    static Single& GetInstance()
    {
        static Single single;
        return single;
    }

    int doSomething()
    {
        while ( !started )
            std::this_thread::sleep_for( std::chrono::milliseconds(100) );

        return 0;
    }

private:
    Single() : 
        started( false ), 
        continueThread( true )
    {
        thread = new std::thread( &Single::threadFunc, this );
    }
    ~Single()
    {
        continueThread = false;
        thread->join();
        delete thread;
    }

    void threadFunc()
    {
        started = true;
        while ( continueThread )
        {
            std::this_thread::sleep_for( std::chrono::milliseconds(1) );
        }
    }

    std::atomic_bool started;
    std::atomic_bool continueThread;
    std::thread* thread;
};

int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
    return Single::GetInstance().doSomething();
}
```

If this is copied to a single main.cpp file and executed, everything works fine. When `~Single` is executed, in the debugger, I see the `threadFunc` thread is running and it gets stopped cleanly.

Now, if `Single` definition and implementation is moved to a separate dll. When `~Single` is executed, in the debugger, I see the `threadFunc` thread is not running anymore (the system already stopped it) and the code can't stop in cleanly. Visual Leak Detector reports then a memory leak.

Is there any flag (in code or at compiler level) that could be set to guarantee threads are not destroyed before the singleton gets deleted?

I know I could call a deinit function manually from the `main` function, but at some point, the `main` may not even know there is singleton running a thread in the shared library it uses...the shared library itself should be able to cleanly exit.

Comment: You don't have to make it a pointer to a `std::thread` - just make it `std::thread thread;`.  If MSVC have implemented the C++20 `std::jthread` you can also use that to let it auto join on destruction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

Multithreading, automatic cleanup, and DLL unloading are basically a huge mess on Windows once they interact.

The solution is to not have singletons, or any static lifetime variables (globals, local statics, class statics) with non-trivial destruction semantics. Make an instance of your thing in `main()`/`WinMain()`. Pass a reference to whoever needs it. Let the destructor clean it up *before* `main` exits and thus before everything gets unloaded.

Or simply ignore the memory leak. The process is exiting anyway.

Comment: "Or simply ignore the memory leak. The process is exiting anyway", Yeah, but this pollutes my leak log (trying to have no leak reported at all. That's the kind of answer I was expecting to get in the end...Windows makes things behave badly. Let's see if someone else has a better solution!

Answer (score 1):

This a common case of SUOF (Static Unitialization Order Fiasco) caused by giving up control over object instance lifetime by using static local variable. Solution is to get back control over object instance lifetime by adding a couple of initialization / uninitialization routines (probably wrapped with RAII) that will ensure that object is created before the first use and destroyed after last use but prior to dll getting unloaded / `main` function returning.

Comment: Thanks. Is there no portable to catch event when library is being unloaded so that it can cleanly delete it's static objects right away?

Comment: @jpo38 There is no need to catch this event. CRT typically captures this event and triggers cleanup destroying static and global variables essentially leading to SUOF. The whole point of this answer is to avoid implicit indeterminate cleanup.